# DIctionary retrieved from ViewState does not contain a key

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, viewstate

I have a code that inserts `<key,value>` into `Dictionary`, put `Dictionary` into `ViewState` and than later on retrieves that `Dictionary` from `ViewState`.

This is when I populate `Dictionary` and put it in `ViewState`:

```
foreach (DataTable table in IsoDataSet.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        if (dr.IsNull("email"))
        {
            email = "No emails on file";
        }
        else
        {
            email = (String)dr["email"];
        }

        oldEmails.Add((String)dr["isonum"], email);
        ViewState["OldEmails"] = oldEmails;
    }
}
```

Then I need to get `Dictionary` back from `ViewState`:

```
oldEmails = (Dictionary<String, String>)ViewState["OldEmails"];
```

When doing `oldEmails.Count`, I see that I have the same amount of records in my `Dictionary` as were placed there in the beginning.

But when I do a check: `if(oldEmails.ContainsKey(strIsoNum))` it fails., event though I have a data in my Dictionary with the given key

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it fails ??? What is the exception/Error you get, or it just doesn't find the key ?

Comment: Have you verified that `strIsoNum` has the value you expect? Have you tried looping through the dictionary to see what values it _does_ contain?

Comment: I mean, it does not fail with an error, it just does not go inside of `if` condition, meaning it cannot find a key

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is not serializable, and can not be saved on view state.

To save it on view state you need to convert it to a `List` or something other, and again re-convert it to `Dictionary` on page load and before you use it.

So that why when you try to save it on view state, view state actually not saves because can not serialize it. Even better use direct a `List` especial if you do not have too many items to search inside the list.

Some q/a on how to serialize dictionary.

[Serializing .NET dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299071/serializing-net-dictionary)
[Serialize Class containing Dictionary member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member)

And one answer on 
[How to store list of object into ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437820/how-to-store-list-of-object-into-viewstate/13437873#13437873)

Comment: *Dictionary is not serializable, and can not be saved on view state.* It's annotated with SerializableAttribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is I din't know that, nether have try it - So if its add this attribute can make it work then.

Comment: I tried to do what I did 2 days ago just right now with Visual Studio 2012. I saved my `Dictionary` into `ViewState` without converting it into `List` and then checked for the key and it worked. Even though `Dictionary` is not `serializable`. Why is that?